# Why the text is wrapped (hyphenated), but without hyphens shown

Tags: css, word-wrap, hyphenation, css-hyphens

This is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  
  <ol class="meaning">
    <li class="meaning-item">This is the example of the sentence where the long words should be hyphenated
      <ul class="sentences">
        <li class="sentence">This is the example of the sentence where the long words should be hyphenated</li>
        <li class="translation">This is the example of the sentence where the long words should be hyphenated</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
  
</body>
</html>

.meaning {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 2.5vw);
  word-break: break-all;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.meaning > li {
  position: relative;
}

.meaning > li::before {
  content: counter(item);
  counter-increment: item;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: calc(-0.7em - 2.5vw);
}

.sentences {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

The words are wrapped as I want them to, but the hyphen itself ("-") is not shown at the point where the word is wrapped.
 Besides, I want to *explicitly* tell the browser that text in `<li class="sentence">` is in English (en) and in `<li class="translation">` - in German (de). I know that not all browsers have built-in instructions for hyphening specific languages, but I want to give it a try.
 I also [saved](https://jsbin.com/nocuqeyeno/edit?html,css,output) this code in the JS Bin. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Don't use `word-break: break-all;` – it breaks words at *any* position, regardless of hyphenation rules.

2.) You need a `lang` attribute in the `html` tag in combination with `hyphens: auto;` to activate automatic hyphenation.

3.) You can use a *different* `lang` attribute in any element that contain another language – see how I applied `lang="de"` to the last `li` element below.

```css
.meaning {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  font-size: calc(0.7em + 2.5vw);
  hyphens: auto;
}

.meaning > li {
  position: relative;
}

.meaning > li::before {
  content: counter(item);
  counter-increment: item;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: calc(-0.7em - 2.5vw);
}

.sentences {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  
  <ol class="meaning">
    <li class="meaning-item">This is the example of the sentence where the sophisticated extraordinariliy long words should be hyphenated
      <ul class="sentences">
        <li class="sentence">This is the example of the sentence where the long words should be hyphenated</li>
        <li class="translation" lang="de">Das ist ein Beispiel für einen Satz, der außergewöhnlich überlange Wörter enthält, welche am Zeilenende bei Bedarf geteilt werden sollen.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! However, your version of the code moves *whole words* on the next line, not hyphenates (splits) them. I see it in Opera Desktop here on Stackoverflow and also on JS Bin I made (https://jsbin.com/pewoxalufa/edit?html,css,output). What may be the root of the problem in your opinion?

Comment: In Firefox it hyphenates the words as intended, both in English as in German. As stated on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens , it also requires that "the appropriate hyphenation dictionary is available". So it seems to be a browser issue. However, according to caniuse (https://caniuse.com/?search=hyphens), 95% of all browsers worldwide support `hyphenation: auto`.

Comment: BTW, also in the JS Bin you made *and*  in the Stack Overflow snippet, the words *are*  hyphenated when I open it. You should check your browser, I suppose...

Comment: You're right: it **does** work in Opera Mobile, so looks like something is wrong on the Opera Desktop side. Thank you so much for your help!